# How do I use /testfor on a scoreboard on Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

On Bedrock Edition, I'm trying to make a game and I only need to put in a system to see if a team has 10 points so they can win the game. I also don't know how to get an output from the command block. I tried `/testfor Blue[scores={Score=10}]`

(`Score` is the objective)

Of course, I am using a fake player to keep score of each team. Does this change the way it outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test a fake player's score, use `/scoreboard players test` instead of `/testfor`.

```
/scoreboard players test Blue Score 10 10
```

The first `10` is the min, the 2nd `10` is the max.